# Resolve/Download dependencies after deployment to remote server

Tags: java, maven

I have a big war file over-sized due to lots of external dependencies & also I have internet connection speed issues because of which I don't want to keep the dependency jars in my war, so that I could reduce war size & do faster uploads of my updated wars from dev machine to remote server.

I would like the maven project to instead download the dependencies on the remote tomcat server itself when it has been uploaded there & starts running. How do I configure maven to do that ?

Comment: Did you try to run a "mvn dependency:resolve" on the remote server?

Comment: @Guillaume: No I didn't tried but how should I prevent dependencies from being added to war ? Using dependency scope `provided` ? Anything else after that?

Comment: @Guillaume Could you please clarify this a bit more stating as an answer so that I could accept ?!

Answer (score 2):

There is a pretty simple solution: Build the project on the server.

An easy way to do this is to put all the sources into a version control system like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

In addition to giving you a history and an automated backup, DVCS have insanely efficient algorithms to update remote copies (they just transfer the changes, so if you change a single line, only one line is sent over the wire).

Building on your server also means that you get the very fast download of dependencies on the server (which has probably very good download rates). And local deployment will be very, very fast.

Last but not least: When you use version control, you will be able to go back to the last stable version quickly when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Aarom says you should build the project on the server directly.

There are two requirements:

- You need to have a command line access on the remote server.
- Maven must be installed on the remote server.

Then you can upload the sources of your project on the remote server (without dependencies).
Go in the root directory of your project and run your build command (`mvn package` or whatever custom build command that you use).

So that's it, you have the .war on the remote server loaded with all the dependencies; you can then remove the source files.

Answer (score 0):

@user01

1. Install all desired 3rd-party jars to Tomcat's lib folder.
2. Set the scope of those dependencies to "provided" in you Maven pom.xml.
3. Install Maven on your remote server.
4. Install a CI server such as Jenkins, Continuum, Bamboo, Hudson, CruiseControl, etc.  I'd suggest Jenkins.
5. Hopefully, you are using revision control software such as SVN, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, or CVS.  If not, then I'd suggest setting up
   Git or SVN for your source code repository.
6. Configure the scm tag in your pom.xml to point to your project's location within your source code repository.
7. Configure your CI server to get your pom.xml from your source code repository.  Your CI server will read the scm tag, and the
   URL's you've configured within the scm tag, and will check your
   project out.  Your CI server will then build your project.
8. You can either have Jenkins deploy your built war artifact to Tomcat via the Jenkins Deploy Plugin, or you can use a Maven plugin such as the
   tomcat7-maven-plugin or Cargo.